# How is the File class implemented for multiple platforms

Tags: java

How is the File Class defined in java?

Since java is a platform neutral language and every operating system has different file systems:
Windows uses NTFS and linux uses Mount.

Comment: Every OS is not different; these days (>~1988) they're almost all [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-ish.

Comment: Is your question about how the .class file is portable? And Linux uses ext4/zfs/xfs as file systems, not "mount". You [can read about the class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) if that is your question. Otherwise, please edit to clarify exactly what knowledge you seek.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Virtual Machine or Java Runtime Environment, provides the operating system(Windows or Linux) and architecture(Arm, x86, x64, Power) specific code to implement the exposed Java functions in a consistent manner across all platforms.